# libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Il2CppExceptionWrapper on restore IAP

Tags: ios, xcode8, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am Usind SDKBOX IAP for my in-app purchases in my app
when I build the app on ipad I am able to successfully purchase an item and everything is fine. When I quit my app and reopen it and then whenever I try to call restore app crashes with the following error.

I am testing on xcode 8.2.1/8.0 and using unity 5.4.2p4/5.5.1p3

> free`il2cpp::vm::Exception::Raise:

showing this log when crashed

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type Il2CppExceptionWrapper

[image: Crash log]

Answer (score 2):

The type `Il2CppExceptionWrapper` is used by IL2CPP to throw managed exceptions. So this indicates that your code is causing a managed exception to occur. It is possible to debug the generated C++ code in Xcode to determine why this exception occurs. Check out the following resources we have created:

Blog post discussing how to do this: https://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/20/il2cpp-internals-debugging-tips-for-generated-code/

Video of us doing this on stage: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s7Ple1G83jc

Slides from the video: https://www.slideshare.net/joncham/il2cpp-debugging-and-profiling

Comment: This answer is helpful but we cannot set the name of an *Exception Breakpoint* with Xcode 10.1.